# How to dynamically download and execute Dart code in a flutter app?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a flutter mobile app and i would like to be able to download dart code into the app and execute it. The downloaded code is fully trusted i.e. it comes from API calls to the mobile apps backend. There are two cases.

- **Non UI downloaded code:** This is downloaded dart code that can interact with the network and and do some data structure transformations. It might also want to interact with the SQLLite database used by the app.
- **UI code**: code that can interact with specific widgets on the screen or draw new widgets?

Can the above two dynamic code execution be done in a production flutter app that has been complied to native code?

Comment: As far as I know this isn't possible because the code would have to be compiled at some point, which I don't believe is possible to do dynamically. Out of curiosity, why do you want to do this?

Comment: I have a hypermedia API that the mobile app talks to. I want to do some smart things  in the mobile app to make the UI adapt to the hypermedia instructions. I am hopping to figure out how to have a second dart isolate that runs the downloaded code. Being able to send code back to the hypermedia client will make the client super powerful.

Comment: Why can't this be done without sending _code_?

Comment: It can to a limited extent but there are more possibilities for making things interesting. if I can execute code dynamically.

Comment: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/14330